# How can I set priority for custom operators?

Tags: f#, operators

How can I set priority for custom operators? (if that is possible)

like `*` or `/` has higher priority then `+` or `-` I want to add such rule to my operators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precedence is decided by the table at the bottom of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx

In particular the order is :

> |,',',||,&,&&,< op, >op, =, |op, &op,&&& , |||, ^^^, ~~~, <<<, >>>,^ op,::,- op, +op,
>   (binary),* op, /op, %op,** op,prefix operators (+op, -op, %, %%, &, &&, !op, ~op)

From the same page:

> F# supports custom operator overloading. This means that you can
>   define your own operators. In the previous table, op can be any valid
>   (possibly empty) sequence of operator characters, either built-in or
>   user-defined. Thus, you can use this table to determine what sequence
>   of characters to use for a custom operator to achieve the desired
>   level of precedence. Leading . characters are ignored when the
>   compiler determines precedence.